# subscribe to address (wallet) and get transaction info including receiving token name (if token)

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I just started playing arround with blockchain development and the use of web3 so I have more questions than my fingers are able to type, hope some of you are able to answer the first one I have.

What I want to archieve is following:
Subscribe to an address (wallet) and then stream all transactions going out- or going in for this address.

I also want to know for example, if the wallet makes an outgoing transaction to another address, what Token had been sent. I hope this makes sense or is even possible.

Like I want to know if wallet A sends funds to wallet B and what kind of token had been sent.

This is what I got so far, need help to get in the right direction for the rest of what I am trying to do.

```
var subscription1 = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'
}, function (error, result) {
})
.on("data", function (log) {
    //console.log(log);
    web3.eth.getTransaction(log.transactionHash)
        .then(function (transaction) {
            console.log(transaction)
            if (transaction.value > 0) {
                console.log("Ether sent from " + transaction.from + " to " + transaction.to)
            }
        })
})
```

I am also unclear about, why the subscription outputs a console.log at the very beginning containing an transaction array and other information, as I expected to only receive data in the "on data" event.

Thank you for reading, hoping someone has the patient to help me out stepping into the topic.

Regards